# Python: List is overwritten. But Why?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

The following code:

```
file_path = 'some_path/data.txt'
exp = loadtxt(file_path)

signal_exp = []
signal_exp.append(exp[1, :])

signal_exp_new = []
signal_exp_new.append(signal_exp[0])

signal_exp_new[0][0:800] = 0.0
```

will result in `signal_exp` beeing overwritten at the first 800 elements as well as `signal_exp_new`. I found the solution but I do not understand why the next one works as expected (of me at least):

```
file_path = 'some_path/data.txt'
exp = loadtxt(file_path)

signal_exp = []
signal_exp.append(exp[0, :].tolist())

signal_exp_new = []
signal_exp_new.append(signal_exp[0][:])

for l in range(800):
    signal_exp_new[0][l] = 0.0
```

Can anyone give me an explanation why in the latter case, the original list is not overwritten but in the first case it is?

Comment: because  `[:]` creates a slice copying the complete list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy array slicing and Python list slicing work differently. Slicing on Python lists returns a shallow copy of the list, while on NumPy arrays it simply returns a view of the array items.

From NumPy [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options):

> Note that slices of arrays do not copy the internal array data but
>   also produce new views of the original data.

So, in your first solution you can use `.copy` to get a copy of the array:

```
signal_exp_new.append(signal_exp[0].copy())
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator [:] returns a slice of a sequence. Slicing a portion of a list: create a new list, and copy the portion of the original list into this new list.

Without [:], no new list is created. signal_exp[0] and signal_exp_new[0] refers to the same list.

http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list

Answer (score 1):

in the first snippet you're using pointer arithmethic. This means that you don't copy the entries from `signal_exp[0]` to the new list, but it uses the same object and "attaches" it to the new variable - or in this case to the list element. The `[:]`  creates a copy of the list (but only one element deep).